# Smartest way to union different "layers" in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I'm currently using this crude approach to combine several tables/layers:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW p_impd_800 AS (
SELECT st_union(geom) as geom FROM rt_201
UNION
SELECT st_union(geom) as geom FROM rt_202
UNION
...   
SELECT st_union(geom) as geom FROM rt_207
    );
```

Is there any smarter and faster way you to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're creating a VIEW rather than a TABLE, or just running a SELECT query and processing the results in your system.

Answer: no, as described, there is no better way (except maybe use UNION ALL instead of UNION, to avoid the overhead UNION imposes by trying to ensure all tuples are distinct). With some knowledge of your inputs and *why* you are trying this, perhaps there's some other approach that could be taken.

Comment: Hi Paul, thx for your answer,
First of all, don't pay too much attention at VIEW, TABLE, etc...it's just that I'm like a child trying to take the first steps on the SQL world.
What I'm trying to achieve is an unique layer that will be used in a difference query.